# mod_rewrite and hashtag embedded in URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use `mod_rewrite` to create URLs with embedded `#` symbols?

What user sees:

```
example.com#smith
```

What server sees:

```
example.com/index.php?page=smith
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^#([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Browser does not send hashtag to the server. It is typically used by ajax code, which makes a 'normal' GET/POST request without hashtag, but with arguments corresponding to its action.

Comment: @cheery. So I guess that means it is impossible? Therefore only possibility is like example.com/smith? Only the forward slash can be used in URL (after the TLD)?

Comment: Yes, other functionality can be created with javascript. And no, it can not be used. Especially because it should be url-encoded.

Comment: @Poppy impossible using mod_rewrite yes but not impossible to achieve, you could like Cheery said use JQuery/AJAX to dumb off the client and behind the scenes use the actual entry values to the right URL.

Comment: @Prix If I understand what you are saying, it is possible to create clickable links that display 'example.com#smith', but not possible to enter such a URL directly into a browser and expect the browser to send it to the server correctly?

Comment: @Poppy exactly, since the hashtag is a client side thing used as an anchor, the server does not receive it

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use mod_rewrite to send or convert URLs with hashtags into URLs the server can process. Hashtags are client side features, they are not received at the server level. See comments for more information.